# How to solve equation with rotation and translation matrices?

Tags: math, matrix, computer-vision, linear-algebra, equation-solving

I working on computer vision task and have this equation:

`R0*c + t0 = R1*c + t1 = Ri*c + ti = ... = Rn*c + tn` ,
**n** is about 20 (but can be more if needs)

where each pair of **R**,**t** (rotation matrix and translation vector in 3D) is a result of **i**-measurement and they are known, and vector **c** is what I whant to know.

I've got result with [ceres solver](https://ceres-solver.org). It's good that it can handle outliers but I think it's overkill for this task.

So what methods I should use for two situations:

1. With outliers
2. Without outliers

Comment: Which approach works best for your specific task?

Comment: I'd say the most generic approach is to introduce another vector `a` that is the value of all these expressions and solve the over-determined system `a-Ri*c=ti` by least-squares or similar.

Comment: @LutzL Yes. But how to handle outliers?

Comment: Have you tried using the RANSAC algorithm? It can deal with outliers

Answer (score 0):

To handle outliers you can use RANSAC:

```
 * In each iteration randomly pick i,j (a "sample") and solve c:
   Ri*c + ti = Rj*c + tj
   - Set Y = Ri*c + ti

 * Apply to a larger population:
   - Select S={k} for which ||Rk*c + tk - Y||<e
     e ~ 3*RMS of errors without outliers
   - Find optimal c for all k equations (with least mean square)
   - Give it a "grade": size of S 

 * After few iterations use optimal c found for Max "grade".

 * Number of iterations: log(1-p)/log(1-w^2) 
   [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus]
   p = 0.001  (for example. It is the required certainty of the result)
   w is an assumption of nonoutliers/n.
```